# Caesar Cipher C program not printing

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

Basically what the title says. Can anyone tell me why my program won't print at the end? As far as I can tell the for loop should be rotating each letter but at this point, I have no idea.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{

    int key; 
    bool keyValid = false;

    while (keyValid == false)
    {
        printf("Enter rotation key: ");
        scanf("%d", &key);

        if (key >= 0 && key <= 26)
        {
            keyValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error - key must be in range 0 and 26. Try again. ");
        }
    }

    // printf("Encrypting message (key = %d): %s \n", key, message);

    
    

    if(keyValid == true) {

        char message[80]; 
        printf("Enter message to encrypt: ");
        scanf(" %80[^\n]*s", message);

        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++){
            
            if (isupper(message[i])){
                message[i]= (message[i] - 65 + key) & 26 + 65;
            }
           else  if (islower(message[i])){
                message[i]= (message[i] - 97 + key) & 26 + 97;
            }

        }

        printf("%s", message);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `if (key >= 0 && key <= 26)` ==> `if (key >= 0 && key <= 25)` and  `scanf(" %80[^\n]*s", message);` ==> `scanf(" %79[^\n]", message);`

Comment: @pmg so do i replace the whole check with that one statement?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the program.

Comment: @pmg I think the scanf may be related.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

> ```
> message[i]= (message[i] - 65 + key) & 26 + 65;
>                                     ^    ^
> ```

The expression is evaluated as `(message[i] - 65 + key) & 91` which most likely results in a unprintable character.

---

You want

```
message[i] = ((message[i] - 'A' + key) & 26) + 'A';
```

or, even better, using modulus `%`

```
message[i] = ((message[i] - 'A' + key) % 26) + 'A';    // keep the extra parenthesis!
message[i] = (message[i] - 'A' + key) % 26 + 'A';
```

Comment: What's with the magic `65`?  Why not use `'A'` instead

Comment: I wanted to change as little as possible :-)

Comment: :-( Bad practices should be corrected before they get worse.

Comment: This would explain why it's printing incorrect results. But the question says it's not printing anything at all.

Comment: Right @Barmar: It's printing unprintable characters. Adding to the answer, thanks.

Comment: @pmg wow, stared this code for hours and never noticed the & lmao. You just massively lifted my spirits, thank you. Code works.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations being performed in the following lines produce non-printable results.

```
message[i]= (message[i] - 65 + key) & 26 + 65;
message[i]= (message[i] - 97 + key) & 26 + 97;
```

Replacing both lines with this should do the trick.

```
message[i]= (message[i] + key);
```